# Animating Graphs in xcode with ARKit

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working on an AR app that presents a graph in 3d. 
However, I want to animate the graph and have it form gradually as opposed to the whole graph at once. 
I am not sure how to go about this in xcode :(

Comment: What kind of graph? Where in your project is it set up? How are you adding it to your scene? Any screen shots or code you can post?

Comment: It's a Kaplan Meier graph.  I use image tracking with a picture of the graph to trigger a pre-rendered 3d representation. I have the code for the base operations, nothing for animation. I can share this if you like.

Comment: I think it's best to add as much information as possible. Do so by editing your question to include the code that you have so far and a specific description of what you desire. That will increase the likelihood that someone will be able to help.